# passing struct by reference in c++ doesnt update the value

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

i am passing a struct by reference to one function of a class treestr and storing it there in a vector.

Then passing the same struct by reference to another function and performing some computation on data member of struct. This data member gets updated in the original struct but not in the ones stored in the vector.

(Sorry for any mistakes, new to c++, new to stack overflow). Please help.

```
//Structure description
Struct point{
int x;
int y;
int cal{0};
```

};

```
Struct node{

    point p;
    int data; //value to be updated by func

};

int main(){

    treestr * tree= new treestr(); //create object
    int i=0,n=100;
    vector<node> nob;
    while(i<=n){
        p={1,5}; //some values input by user
        node n={p,i};
        nob.push_back(n)//storing the struct node objects seperately in a 
                         //vector
        treestr->insert(n);  //inserting into tree class
        i++;
        }
    //calling func to do some computation on the struct objects inserted
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x=tree->func(nob[i]);
        cout<<x.cal; //getting updated values from the function
        }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        tree->func2(nob[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

//class description
class treestr{
    vector<node> buck; 
    insert(node& n){
        buck.push_back(n);
        //store nodes
    }

    func(node& n){
        //calculations
        return n.cal; Value got updated in main.
    }
    func2(node &n){
        int val1=n.cal; //this assigns updated value
        int val2=buck[i].p.cal; //this assigns 0(default value)
        if(val1==val2){ //never matches, val2 is 0 for all objects, val1 is 
                           //not after getting updated
        //do something
         }
    }

};
```

The cal gets updated in the main function but not in the class where I have stored. Please ignore grammatical and syntactical mistakes, the code returns correct output however this is something that I need to improve my code.

Any possible reasons??

Comment: `insert(node&)` probably store a copy.

Comment: The shown code won't even compile, and is full of syntax and grammatical errors. Please [edit] your question and make sure it meets all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], if you would like for someone to take their time to help you.

Comment: sorry for the errors, the code is long i cant even post and hard to explain all things.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing
`node n={1,5,0}`

to

```
node * n;
node -> x = 1;
node -> y = 5;
node -> cal = 0;
```

From what I know of pointers you need to assign each value individually.
Also

`tree->insert(n)`

needs to be

`tree.insert(n)`

Another thing

`int node.cal=tree->func(n);`

Not sure what this is supposed to do, but I know it won't work.  'int' needs to be before a variable name.  When accessing `cal` from `node` your call needs to be an `->` and when accessing `func` from `tree` it needs to be a `.`